# Adding and subtracting sum columns in mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL for retrieving all items

```
SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, A.open_stock, B.recd_total, C.issue_qty
FROM chem_master as A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_code, sum(recd_qty) as recd_total
from chem_reciepts GROUP BY item_code) as B on A.item_code=B.item_code
LEFT JOIN(SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty
from chem_issue GROUP BY item_code) as C on A.item_code=C.item_codeand
```

the returned data is

```
Item_code Description                      unit op.stock recd_total issue_qty

25139     ALUMINIUM OXIDE ACTIVE NEUTRAL   GM       0         0          0
54006     L-ASCORBIC ACID                  GM       0         0          0
AC001     ACETIC ACID GLACIAL              LTR      0         14         2
AC002     ACETONE AR                       LTR      0         0          0
AC005     ACACIA POWDER                    GM       0         0          0
```

I want only those records where `open_stock + recd_total - issue_qty = 0`

How to modify sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `having` with the condition you mentioned to your query(at the end of query).
 Something like below:

```
HAVING op.stock+recd_total-issue_qty=0
```

Comment: Tried this, it is partly working. Because the resultant data has Null values in recd_qty and iss_qty columns because for some records in the master table there is no record in receipt table or issue table. Insteab of giving balance = 0, if I give balance >0 it is showing records having available stock. How to resolve?

Comment: @mansoondreamz you want the rows with null values in any of the columns or not

Comment: This is working   SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, A.open_stock, B.recd_total, C.issue_qty FROM chem_master as A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_code, sum(recd_qty) as recd_total from chem_reciepts GROUP BY item_code) as B on A.item_code=B.item_code LEFT JOIN(SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty from chem_issue GROUP BY item_code) as C on A.item_code=C.item_code HAVING (open_stock+recd_total-issue_qty) IS NULL OR (open_stock+recd_total-issue_qty)=0

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT q.*, (q.stock+(q.recd_total-q.issue_qty)) as resultant FROM (
SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, A.open_stock, B.recd_total, C.issue_qty
FROM chem_master as A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_code, sum(recd_qty) as recd_total
from chem_reciepts GROUP BY item_code) as B on A.item_code=B.item_code
LEFT JOIN(SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty
from chem_issue GROUP BY item_code) as C on A.item_code=C.item_codeand
) q  HAVING q.resultant =0
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and HAVING resultant= 0' at line 8

Comment: try this ` q.resultant =0`

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
SELECT A.item_code,A.description,A.uom, A.open_stock, B.recd_total, C.issue_qty
FROM chem_master as A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_code, sum(recd_qty) as recd_total
from chem_reciepts GROUP BY item_code) as B on A.item_code=B.item_code
LEFT JOIN(SELECT item_code, sum(iss_qty) as issue_qty
from chem_issue GROUP BY item_code) as C on A.item_code=C.item_codeand 
having op.stock+recd_total-issue_qty = 0;
```